# C++ on Linux - How do I #define a #ifdef / #endif debug conditional

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, c-preprocessor

I want to trace my code if `DEBUG` is defined, as in the following `#ifdef` code block:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    OP_LOG(debug) << "SEQUENCE:  " __FILE__ << "::" << __FUNCTION__;
#endif
```

Someone said I could use a `#define` so that the above three lines would only be one line instead. This is the closest I could get to figuring it out, but it gives tracing output unconditionally, whether or not `DEBUG` is defined:

```
#define DEBUG_TRACE(note) OP_LOG(debug) << "SEQUENCE :  " << __FILE__ <<"::" <<__FUNCTION__ << note
```

I don't know how to make a conditional `#define`. Is this possible, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Someone said I could create a #define, so that the above three lines would only be one line instead.

Not that I have heard of. My favorite way to do this would be

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_LOG OP_LOG(debug) << "SEQUENCE:  " __FILE__ << "::" << __FUNCTION__;
#else
#define DEBUG_LOG
#endif
```

This way you have to only write DEBUG_LOG where ever you want to log only if `-DDEBUG` is set.

---

#### The way it works:

Look at the `#ifdef`, `#else`, `#endif` statement. We define `DEBUG_LOG` to be expanded to nothing when `-DDEBUG` isn't set and as `OP_LOG(debug) << "SEQUENCE:  " __FILE__ << "::" << __FUNCTION__;` if it is. That way you don't have to worry about `-DDEBUG` later on, you just have to use `DEBUG_LOG` when you want to place a trace call.

Answer (score 5):

You can't put `#ifdef` in the replacement part of a `#define`, but you *can* use `#define` *inside* an `#ifdef`/`#endif` block, like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_TRACE(note) ... // put your debug code here
#else
#define DEBUG_TRACE(note)
#endif
```

In the `#else` case, this defines `DEBUG_TRACE` to expand to nothing if `DEBUG` isn't defined.